# Updating a many-to-many field of a model using partial update - only non-relations and foreign keys permitted

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I would like to update many-to-many field of a model using partial update. However I get the error

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: skills> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).
```

This is what my model currently looks like

```
class modelJob(models.Model):
    skills              = models.ManyToManyField(modelSkill,blank=True)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False,blank=False,null=True)
    moreInfo            = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=False,blank=False,null=True)
```

This is what my serializer looks like

```
class Serializer_PartialUpdateJob_RX(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        modelJob.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        job = modelJob.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        return job
```

and this is what my view looks like

```
class PartialUpdate_Jobs(GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = modelJob.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializer_PartialUpdateJob_RX
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result =  self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(Serializer_Job_TX(self.queryset[0]).data)
```

Now I would only like to update the many-many field (skills) and this is what my json looks like

```
{
    "skills" :[ 
               2,4
             ]
}
```

where 2 and 4 are the ids of the skill objects at this point I get the error

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: skills> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in your serializer's update function.

First you introduce 'skills' as serializer's attributre which is list of skills ids. You might call it something else, if you want to use the same serializer to list but as your chosen name  suggests to be  'partial' serializer, i assume it is used only to update.

```
class Serializer_PartialUpdateJob_RX(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    skills = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=modelSkill.objects.all(), write_only=True, many=True, required=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
         skills = validated_data.pop('skills', None)
         instance = super().update(instance, validated_data) # if you want to update other fields

         # now update skills 
         if skills is not None:
             for skills in skills:
                 instance.skills.add(skill)
             instance.save()

         return instance
```

Comment: This would not remove any skill that was removed in the payload